# solving null pointer exception occuring in web app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-applications, hql

So I have been writing code for my web application and I have come across a problem, here are my program files

here's my controller code:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.List;
import model.dao.ICartDAO;
import model.daoimpl.CartDAOImpl;
import model.entity.Cart;
import model.entity.Products;
import model.entity.Userinfo;
import model.service.ICartService;

@Controller
public class CartController {
    @Autowired
    private ICartService icartservice;

    public String getLoggedInUserName() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = authentication.getName();
        return name;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addcartitem")
    public String addCartItem(@RequestParam(value="productId")String productId,
            @ModelAttribute("Cart")Cart c, @ModelAttribute("User")Userinfo u, @ModelAttribute("Product")Products p) { 

        boolean b;
        u.setUserName(getLoggedInUserName());
        p.setProductId(Integer.parseInt(productId));
        c.setProduct(p);
        c.setUserInfo(u);
        b=this.icartservice.addCartItem(c);


        if(b) 
            return "success";
        else 
            return "newhomepage";
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showcart",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCart(Model model) {
        List<Products> products =  this.icartservice.getCartForUser(getLoggedInUserName());
        model.addAttribute("products",products);
        return "cart";
    }
}
```

DAO class:

```
package model.daoimpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import model.config.HibernateUtil;
import model.dao.ICartDAO;
import model.entity.Cart;
import model.entity.Products;

public class CartDAOImpl implements ICartDAO {
    private Session sess;
    public CartDAOImpl() {
        sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    }
    public boolean addCartItem(Cart c) {
         boolean b = true;

         try {
             sess.beginTransaction();
             sess.save(c);
             sess.getTransaction().commit();

         } catch(Exception ex) {
             b = false;
             sess.getTransaction().rollback();
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }

         return b;
    }


    public List<Products> getCartForUser(String userName) {
        List<Products> l=null;
        try {
            sess.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "FROM Products,Cart,Userinfo where (Userinfo.userName=Cart.userName  AND Userinfo.userName = ?) AND Products.productId=Cart.productId";
            l = sess.createQuery(hql,Products.class).setParameter(0,userName).getResultList();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

service class:

```
package model.serviceimpl;

@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements ICartService {
    private ICartDAO icartdao;

    public void setICartDAO(ICartDAO icartdao) {
        this.icartdao=icartdao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addCartItem(Cart c) {
        return this.icartdao.addCartItem(c);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Products> getCartForUser(String userName) {
        return this.icartdao.getCartForUser(userName);
    }

}
```

MVC spring web config:

```
package config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("controller")
public class MvcSpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/Views/", ".jsp");
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ICartService icartservice() {
        return new CartServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

error after edit:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ProjectFE/showcart: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.serviceimpl.CartServiceImpl.getCartForUser(CartServiceImpl.java:33)
    at controller.CartController.showCart(CartController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    ... 79 more
```

so after running the webapp I keep getting following error `ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.NullPointerException`

So I don't get which variable here is not getting assigned so that I am getting the above error, If you guys can find something please help.

If any more code is needed please comment

Comment: can you post the error with stack trace

Comment: Can your provide whole exception? Btw. how do you inicialize `sess` ?

Comment: can you atleast update the complete code @Mob_Abominator

Comment: yep updated @Deadpool

Comment: follow `@ville` answer, if you are using spring you should not create object leave that top spring, Annotate `CartDAOImpl with `@Service` and Autowire it in controller

Comment: can you explain it in brief ? exactly what needs to be changes I'm a bit confused

Comment: I did as you said but it still won't work, I have updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

With Spring you use Service layer for methods to handle data. You annotate services with @Service or @Component. 
Use Autowired allways to use another class methods. 
@Autowired
private Class class

For managing SQL databases https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Edit:
This interface connects to your database

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    Person findByEmail(String email);

}



    @Entity
    public class Person{
       private String email;
       private String name;

    constructors, getters and setters.
}

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public PersonDto getPerson(Principal principal) {

        Person person = this.personRepository.findByEmail(principal.getName());
        return new PersonDto(person.getEmail(), person.getName() );
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public class UserApi {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("user")
    public PersonDto getUser(Principal principal) {

        return this.userService.getPerson(principal);
    }
}
```

DTO includes only constructors, getters and setters. It is only for passing data. In this example it is exactly same than Person entity.

Comment: I tried my @Service as you and got null pointer error. With autowire works fine.

Comment: I copy from my own project a cleaned sample.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Actually what I need to change in my code is not clear from what you've posted above, can you point out what stuff do I need to change in my code above ? Also I have a Interface so should I delete that interface ? And instead Autowire it ? And finally where should I add the @service annotation ?

Comment: I think you have to do separate service class and annotate that with @Service

Comment: hey man I have updated my code see above, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: CartServiceImpl.getCartForUser() seems to return null. I prefer to use interface to manage database queries. Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html. You have to@Autowire private ICartDAO icartdao;

Comment: okay I'll try that but before that is my bean declaration in the config file is correct ?

Comment: I do not see need for bean. Are you sure that your Query will return anything. I am not familiar with hibernate but quick look from documentation and mayby you have to use Query<Products> query = sess.createQuery.... and then to l = query.list();